# Support 16:9 video on website (Adobe Flash Player & FMIS)

Tags: apache-flex, video, widescreen

When implementing a video player using Adobe Flex to support 16:9 video, how do we know the video source is a 16:9 video?

Because I want to adjust the UI layout according to the aspect of video source? Also, do we have to upgrade version of streaming server, e.g. Adobe FMIS, so as to support 16:9 video?

One last question: do we just leave the ability to play 16:9 video to Flash Player or do I have to do some works first in the video player?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the video meta data, to get the sizes, and calculate the aspect ratio.

I do not think it is necessary to upgrade to a newer version of the server for streaming 16:9. It is more about the codec that you will be streaming. To get H.264/AAC codec support, you most likely need to upgrade.

Some interesting topics are found here:

[Flash media Server](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/beginning-fms45-pt02.html)

[Flash Media Encoder with Livestream](http://www.livestream.com/userguide/index.php?title=Use_Flash_Media_Encoder_On2_Flix_live_or_Wirecast_with_Livestream)

Also look at www.red5.org for a Free Media Streaming server option.